# In Excel2016, I have a cell containing specific text and a number. I want to add that number to other numbers in a range

Tags: worksheet-function

In Excel 2016, I have a cell containing specific text and a number.  I want to add that number (not the text) to other numbers in a range, but do nothing if that specific text isn't also in the cell.  I'm trying to calculate amounts of leave taken by types of leave used by employees.  They add the amount of leave and the type of leave into a cell which is in a range by pay period.  For instance, they would enter 8LA in cell E6, 8LA in cell F6, and 8SL in cell G6  if they were taking vacation on January 7th and 8th and sick leave on January 9th.  I want all vacation hours to tabulate in cell S6 (E6+F6) and all sick hours to tabulate in cell V6. Cell S6 would = 16; cell V6 would = 8.  The text would be ignored except to tell it which cells to include in cells S6 and V6. I haven't played with formulas for a few years, and I'm stumped!  Help, please!

Comment: Think about separating the number and the code into separate cells.  It really simplifies things.

Comment: Thank you, fixer1234! I actually considered that. I haven't completely ruled it out,  but, most of my end-users are not very experienced with using Excel, and I'm not the original creator of it. Like I said, I haven't completely ruled that option out.  I didn't mention before that the cells they enter into (in this case E6, F6, and G6) are conditionally formatted to change color when text is entered -- lilac when 'LA' is typed; red when 'SL' is typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, name a range where the leave time and class will be entered.
That range, you said, is on row 6, cells E-G (shown in my example in tan)

Then, we need two hidden rows, which could be anywhere; in my example, the LA row is one line below (row 7) and the SL row is two lines below (row 8). Again, they get named as a range, LEAVE and SICK in my example.

Formulas are
=IF(RIGHT(TIME_IN,2)="LA",VALUE(LEFT(TIME_IN,1)),0)  for the LEAVE row (green)
=IF(RIGHT(TIME_IN,2)="SL",VALUE(LEFT(TIME_IN,1)),0)  for the SICK row  (blue)
and in the destination cells to sum up everything
=SUM(LEAVE)
=SUM(SICK)

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that you use `LEFT(G6,LEN(G6)-2)`,  in case values like “2.5SL” or “10LA” ever become valid.

Comment: I'm about to try this.  Scott, 2.5SL and 10LA are certainly valid options right now.  We can take leave in 15 minute increments, and some work 8, 9, 10, or 12 hour days.

Comment: I'd suggest putting the designations LA and SL _before_ the numbers. Why? Because the number of digits for the hours will, as per the above two comments, vary, unlike the original question. When it varies, it's much more difficult to separate the designation from the hours, if the hours precede the designation. If the designation precedes the hours, it's much easier.